# How to Pick up CSS Changes in GWT Application

Tags: gwt, tomcat

Using Tomcat, I build a new WAR via Maven. Then I copy the output WAR to `$TOMCAT_HOME/webapps`. Then, ROOT.war becomes exploded and ROOT appears.

If I modify `ROOT/style/core.css`, will those changes be picked up by my web app at run-time when I re-run `$TOMCAT_HOME/bin/catalina.sh start`?

Note, this is a GWT application.

Comment: Why don't you try and see? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change files in the exploded WAR directory inside your `webapps` folder, the changes will immediately be visible. You don't even have to restart Tomcat for this to work.

Comment: The changes did not work since I'm using GWT. GWT, as I understand, ingests the CSS during compilation. As a result, I did need to re-compile GWT in order to pick up CSS changes.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a dev mode for GWT that will load the CSS as a static file distinct from the rest of the app.  This wold enable normal editing of the file on disk to be seen in your gui.

https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCompilingAndDebugging#DevGuideDevMode